# E/MediaPlayer: setDataSource: IOException! uri= "path of video" error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I am implementing Video View on the list, All video links are having .m3u8 video path (Network buffering videos).

While scrolling a list below error log is printed in logcat :-

> E/MediaPlayer: setDataSource: IOException!
>   uri=https://example.com/a/b/c/Video.m3u8 java.io.FileNotFoundException: No
>   content provider: https://example.com/a/b/c/Video.m3u8
>                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1123)
>                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:958)
>                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:881)
>                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1018)
>                                         at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:437)
>                                         at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:742)
>                                         at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:676)
>                                         at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:203)
>                                         at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
>                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2417)
>                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
>                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6708)
>                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
>                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
>                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
>                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
>                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:822)
>                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5811)
>                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
>                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)

This error always print but Application is still running without crashing.
Sometimes list scrolling gets hanged and ANR is coming.

I have a fragment where I fetch video path from server.
I have adapter, in that onBindViewolder() I assign videoUrl to videoView via 
videoView.setVideoURI(new Uri(videoUrl)).

I need a answer that why my list is not smooth and why I am getting above error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link will solve your problem. https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes. I solved this issue by using onViewDetachedFromWindow() this method of recyclerview.